# Passport req.logOut() is sending error that localhost is not sending any data

Tags: node.js, passport.js, logout, passport-local

```
router.get('/logout', function (req, res) 
{
req.logout();
req.session = null;
res.redirect('/login');
});
```

error-> localhost didn't send any data!
i have tried all the solutions once but still not getting the expected output !

Anykind of help is appreciated !

Comment: passportjs with express session ?

Comment: yes it is passport with express-session module!

Answer (score -1):

with express session module you can :

```
router.get('/logout', function (req, res) 
{
      req.session.destroy(function (err) {
          res.redirect('/login'); 
      });
});
```